# comma in the middle of construction: than... and than

Tags: punctuation, commas

Writing an essay on my trial region English test, I ran into a problem. I wanted to use doubled than, but I was not sure if it's right to do such a thing, and if I should put a comma before the "and than". So, if it wouldn't be a problem, could you please say which phrase (I'll write them both below) is right and, also, explain why?

> Computers have way more occasions to spend time conveniently than people who're claiming this statement to be right are able to imagine, and than I've already mentioned earlier.

> Computers have way more occasions to spend time conveniently than people who're claiming this statement to be right are able to imagine and than I've already mentioned earlier.

I guessed I knew English punctuation a bit, at least a bit. Anyway, we should put a comma before "and" if it connects two sentences in a case when they both have a subject + verb (sorry for a poor phrase, I didn't know how to say it in a proper way). This has seemed to be this case though I thought there's a chance of not putting a comma there due to such a construction as "than... and than".

I appreciate any help.

Comment: The comma is optional (though many readers would appreciate a pause for breath / ease of construing). But  '... I've _already_ mentioned _earlier_'?

Comment: I think you should reword the whole thing -- I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: *Computers have way more occasions **than I've mentioned earlier** to spend time conveniently (?) than **do those** people **who claim** this statement to be right (?) and are able to imagine (?).* That's better, but I still don't understand exactly what's being expressed.

Comment: I was just wondering whether I should put a comma there or not, but must admit this makes no sense without a context. I just thought it would be a lot of text to read if I put all text there, yet your answers are enough to help me figure it out. Thank y'all.